# Javascript : What is the difference between these two fat arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const f = ({x,y})=>{...do something...};

const f = (x,y)=>{...do something...};
```

What is the difference between these two lines ?

My understanding is both pass "x" and "y" are arguments.

Are both the same then ?

Comment: Look for [**Destructing assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: The top function is used in React jsx files to create a Component

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I also failed to name it correctly on the first try :), it's actually called destructuring

Comment: @DanielGrankin LOL. Took me some time to understand your comment. Thank you very very much. I swear every time I stumble upon destruct**ur**ing I get confused as there is no actual destructon of any kind. Now it is all clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one uses destructuring you can use it as

```
f({x: 0, y: 1})
```

you pass one object with fields x and y

and then in body you can access fields of object as variables `x` and `y`.

In the second one you have to pass 2 variables

```
f(0, 1)
```

Bodies can be the same of those functions and they would work analogically
for instance

`=> { return x + y; }`

but params should be passed in different ways

Comment: yes, thank you, just fixed before read your comment :)

Comment: Another *beauty* is that you can pass an entire Object, but thanks to destructuring you make available to your function only a narrower subset of **allowed** (expected) properties `const obj = {x:"foo",y:"bar",z:"baz"}; f(obj)` (where `z` will be ignored)

Comment: The real benefit of such implementation is also that even if you mutate `x` from within your function, it will not mutate it's original Object property value. https://jsfiddle.net/nsLx2873/ - on the other hand if you pass an object as plain argument like in `(obj, x,y)=>` and mutating the object from within the function will also mutate the values at the original reference.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan property can be an object or an array in that case it can be mutated.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan https://jsfiddle.net/0g0f13s1/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159713/discussion-between-daniel-grankin-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score 0):

The first one you're passing an object as a parameter. But I don't think it's a working example. Here is one

```
class O {
  x;
  y;
}
const example =(o:O)=>{
 //do something 
  return o.x+o.y;
};
```

The equivalent is

```
var example = function example(o) {
  //do something 
  return o.x+o.y;
};
```

The second one you're passing two parameters the equivalent is

```
var example2 = function example2(x, y) {
  //do something 
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: what is o:O? is it Flow? types are not supposed to be used in the example